# Change default render option of R's guide_axis()

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart, axis-labels

I was wondering whether it is possible to change the default rendering option of the `guide_axis()` function in `R` (https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/guide_axis.html).

By default, the `n.dodge` attribute alters the number of rows that is used to render the labels for vertical axes and number of columns for horizontal axes.
I would like to transpose this relationship in order to alter the number of label-rows of a vertical axis.

While this might seem counterintuitive at first, it could be useful to solve overlapping labels in a pie chart.

Below is an example to visualize what I mean.

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)


df <- data.frame(name = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'),
                 value = c(1, 1, 1, 97))



p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = '', y = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', width = 1) +
  coord_polar('y', start = 0) +
  theme(legend.position = 'none',
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = sum(df$value) - cumsum(df$value) + df$value/2,
                     labels = paste(df$value, 'Percent', sep = ' '),
                     guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 4))

p
```

[image]

Obviously, the `n.dodge = 4` has no impact on the labels of the pie chart in this example.
Therefore my idea to treat the axis rendering as horizontal, not vertical.

Does such approach make sense in general or is `ggplot`'s labelling organized completely differently anyways?
And if rows for vertical axes make sense, how can I achieve this?

Best,
Oliver

Comment: I don't think `coord_polar()` even makes use of the guide. If you compare `coord_polar()$render_axis_v` with `coord_cartesian()$render_axis_v` you can see that the polar method doesn't pass around any guides and instead has a somewhat hardcoded way of drawing axes. Even if you set `guide = "none"` it still draws the axes.

Answer (score 1):

1. I feel that the `ggplot2` pie charts are usually labeled by `geom_text` instead of axis labels. ([`ggplot2` pie chart gallery](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/piechart-ggplot2.html))
2. To fix the overlapping labels, we can use the package `ggrepel` and replace `geom_text` with `geom_text_repel`. ([An example](https://r-charts.com/part-whole/pie-chart-labels-outside-ggplot2/) of a pie chart with `ggrepel` labels)